# RSVP hash using vanilla promises

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, rsvp.js

[RSVP lib](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js) has a [hash of promises](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/#hash-of-promises) helper that allows to "retrieve" promises references:

```js
var promises = {
  posts: getJSON("/posts.json"),
  users: getJSON("/users.json")
};

RSVP.hash(promises).then(function(results) {
  console.log(results.users) // print the users.json results
  console.log(results.posts) // print the posts.json results
});
```

Is there a way to do such a thing with vanilla promises (in modern ES)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not hard to implement.

```
async function hash(promiseObj) {
  // Deconstitute promiseObj to keys and promises
  const keys = [];
  const promises = [];
  Object.keys(promiseObj).forEach(k => {
    keys.push(k);
    promises.push(promiseObj[k]);
  });
  // Wait for all promises
  const resolutions = await Promise.all(promises);
  // Reconstitute a resolutions object
  const result = {};
  keys.forEach((key, index) => (result[key] = resolutions[index]));
  return result;
}

hash({
  foo: Promise.resolve(8),
  bar: Promise.resolve(16),
}).then(results => console.log(results));
```

Comment: (You can use `Object.entries` too if your target runtime has it.)

Answer (score 0):

OOTB? No, there's only `Promise.all`, but it accepts an array, not a dictionary. But you could create a helper function that accepts a dictionary of promises, converts to array, runs `Promise.all` on it, and processes it with one more `then` converting the results array back into a dictionary.